# como pegar o retorno de um array enviado por um ajax do datatable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Eu estou utilizando o datatables para mostrar os dados da minha tabela... e nele estou precisando fazer alguns filtros personalizados simultâneos.
Eu, basicamente, até então, eu estou enviando a requisição da seguinte forma:

```
 $('#btnFiltro').on( 'click', function () {   // for text boxes
      var dados = new Array();
      $('#frmReportPartners').find(":text:visible,:checkbox:checked,select:visible").each(function(v) {
         dados[v] = $(this).val();
      });
      dataTable.columns().search(dados).draw();
      console.log(dados);    
  });|
```

Agora, após a esse envio, qual forma devo utilizar para poder recuperar e tratar tais informações enviadas, visto que um registro apenas, eu pego assim:

```
if(!empty($requestData['columns'][10]['search']['value'])) {
    $sql .= " AND data_de_aluguel LIKE '" . $requestData['columns'][10]['search']['value'] . "%'";
}
```

Comment: Quando você clica no botão para filtrar, você está passando pelos checkboxes, radios etc e pegando os dados, correto? Aconselho ao invés de usar o índice na função ``$.each()`` usar o nome do ``<input>``, assim: ``dados[$(this).attr('name')]``. Depois, faz um ajax pro seu servidor com os dados ``$.get( "test.php", dados, function(dadosFiltrados){...} );``.

Comment: Se preferir recarregar a página, pode incluir um formulário com todos os campos ``hidden`` e dar um ``submit()`` nele.

Comment: Sim, exatamente @Daniel, mas como assim, usar o nome inputs, um por um?

Comment: Não, lá no loop mesmo. Onde você pega o valor dos checkboxes, usa um objeto ao invés de array (``var dados = {}``) e no callback de ``find`` você usa ``dados[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();`` que aí ele vai criar um objeto montadinho, com o nome dos campos e os valores. Fica mais fácil de tratar do lado do servidor.

Comment: Cara, fazendo os testes eu vi que funciona perfeitamente... ele me retorna arrays, não ta dificil de tratar não

Comment: Tá, agora a dúvida que eu não entendi. Você quer saber a query que vai usar?

Comment: Não.. saber se meu dado tava chegando no php, consegui fazer chegar

Comment: Deixe então a solução como resposta para sua pergunta, assim a galera que chegar nela já terá uma resposta.